# Bootstrap 4 Flexbox divide Screen into 4 parts

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

How can I divide my screen using bootstrap 4 and flexbox into 4 parts which have exactly the same width and height.

Each should have 50% width and height.

They also but be responsive (each content).

So far I tried following without success:

```
    <div id="app" class="flex-container">
        <div class="flex-item" style="background-color:red"></div>
        <div class="flex-item" style="background-color:blue"></div>
        <div class="flex-item" style="background-color:yellow"></div>
        <div class="flex-item" style="background-color:grey"></div>
    </div>


.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use min-width and height of 50%, and wrap the flex, also set the flex container to 100 vh.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.flex-item {
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="app" class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item" style="background-color:red"></div>
  <div class="flex-item" style="background-color:blue"></div>
  <div class="flex-item" style="background-color:yellow"></div>
  <div class="flex-item" style="background-color:grey"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 includes all the flexbox utils you need. Just make sure the container is full-height.

```
<div id="app" class="d-flex mvh-100 flex-wrap">
    <div class="w-50" style="background-color:red"></div>
    <div class="w-50" style="background-color:blue"></div>
    <div class="w-50" style="background-color:yellow"></div>
    <div class="w-50" style="background-color:grey"></div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/6UXPnSgPCs